# can not send variable in ajax. It's undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

in My code i can     alert(edu_id).
But I cannot post value in my controller
And System Alert Undefind After     alert(edu_id).
How to fix ? Thank

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit-edu").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
        var edu_id =$(this).data("id");
        alert(edu_id);
        $.ajax({         
             type: 'POST',
             url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/member/editEducation",
             data : ({edu_id : edu_id}),
             dataType: 'html',
             cache: false,
             success:function(html){
                    $("#edu-id-form").html(html);                           
             }                 
         });       
    });
 })
```

Comment: can you try instead of "data : ({edu_id : edu_id})" please "data : {'edu_id' : edu_id}"

Comment: @Asto: That won't make a difference. The grouping operator returns the result of the expression it contains. I.e. `5` is the same as `(5)` or `((5))` or `(((5)))`.

Comment: use single quote for URL instead of double becayse double quote parse it as string

Comment: You need to show us the markup that this is operating on. We can't tell what `this` is or what `.data("id")` should return.

Comment: @DipeshParmar: Single quotes denote strings too! There is no difference between single or double quotes.

Comment: @DipeshParmar — There is no difference between single and double quotes in JavaScript (other than which characters need to be escaped inside strings delimited with different quotes).

Comment: Maybe try `$(this).id`

Comment: @matino: jQuery objects don't have an `id` property.

Comment: <a href="#" class="edit-edu" data-id="<?php echo $education->edu_id;?>"> link </a> This is my link

Comment: Show us the HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: <a href="#" class="edit-edu" data-id="1">                                   <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are reading the variable with $(this).data("id"). Since $(this) is pointing at the control itself, maybe you should try to read with $(this).attr("id"), since ID is an actual attribute:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName

Comment: Actually, this solution depends on the real HTML structure. I assumed (maybe I'm mistaken) that ID is an attribute of a class="edit-edu" element.

Comment: <a href="#" class="edit-edu" data-id="<?php echo $education->edu_id;?>">

Comment: Thanks, Sarun. In this case, you can try to use $(this).attr("data-id"). Maybe $(this).data("id") overrides with some other attribute of jQuery. Cannot test it right now, sorry :( .

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: <a href="#" class="edit-edu" data-id="<?php echo $education->edu_id;?>"> link </a>
This is my link